# Why didn't Harry offer for one of the Order members to ride his Firebolt in the battle of the Seven Potters?

Tags: harry-potter

He had the best racing broom in the world, and he ends up losing it.

Tonks, Arthur or Mad-Eye could have used Harry's Firebolt instead of their much slower brooms, and Harry probably wouldn’t have lost his broom.

It seems like a waste to not use his Firebolt in this situation, where speed and agility mattered greatly.

Comment: If you're trying to confuse the enemy by making everyone look identical, it doesn't make much sense to give one person an obviously different broom.

Comment: When Harry first gets the broom, he spends a considerable amount of time practicing with it, learning to control it. The others don't have the luxury of time to familiarise themselves with its speed and responsiveness.

Comment: @phantom42 which is why you put the actual special one on motorcycle?

Comment: JKR is not great at strategy or math. But making one bad choice does not make other bad choices better.

Answer (score 8):

I’ll throw out a couple of suggestions:

- **Nobody else knows how to control it like him.**

  The performance of the Firebolt is completely different to that of a regular broom. Harry took to it reasonably well, but remember that he first used it after learning on a racing broom. Harry can’t ride on the broom, because it’ll draw attention:

  > “We think the Death Eaters will expect you to be on a broom,” said Moody, who seemed to guess how Harry was feeling.

  But for the Aurors, trying to control the broom would distract them from the main task of fighting off Death Eaters. They need their wits about them, so the potential advantages of using the Fireboat don't offset the costs.
- **He didn’t think of it.**

  Another very plausible candidate. It’s a very high-stress scenario: he’s about to leave the Dursleys forever, knowing he’ll have to fight through Death Eaters and Voldemort to escape, with thirteen of his friends with him who are all ready to die, and so on.

  It’s not the best time to be making decisions, and since the logistics are already sorted, he may not have thought to suggest it. (And he seems more preoccupied with the people turning into him than anything else.)
- **It's not actually a good strategy.**

  Even if he had suggested it (or Ron or Hermione, who could have brought it up in the planning meeting), it might have been rejected.

  The Firebolt has such a performance advantage that it effectively puts anybody flying it in a completely different class to the other six pairs. The point of having seven Potters is to confuse the Death Eaters, so picking out one pair with a much faster broom is a poor strategy.

  The Death Eaters would focus on the Firebolt first, trying to kill the riders before the others were off the ground. It would meet very heavy resistance. Once it’s either dead or escaped, the Death Eaters have one less target to attack, and there’s more for each of the remaining six.

  This isn’t better for anybody: all seven pairs will be subject to heavier Death Eater resistance than if they hadn’t used the in-another-class-of-performance racing broom.

Answer (score 1):

Anybody using firebolt would be targeted first. Although everybody had volunteered to join in, using the firebolt would have been nothing short of committing suicide. Secondly I don't think Harry would have allowed it.